# Cant login using htpasswd when username is full email

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

Site is using Joomla, and has login box on page (not http auth popup box)
I have a script that add a username and pw to the htpasswd file, but the username is a full email, ie me@mine.com

The script add the login fine, but I can not log into via the Joomla login box.

If I manually change the username in the htpasswd removing the @ sign it works fine.

Any way around this?

Server issue, or more like Joomla?

TIA!

Comment: I think you should post the script. It may well be that it contains the actual problem.

Comment: A problem could be if you use it in the url pattern (user:password@server) it would confuse the browser that you use two at signs.